# Abnormal sendmail activity using up the server memory on my Ubuntu 12.04 server

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, sendmail, spam, wordpress, low-memory

#### Environment

- Rackspace
- Ubuntu 12.04
- Wordpress
- MySql

#### The issue

I have been experiencing quite serious out-memory-issues in the last couple of days.

While [I resolved one possible cause the issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/614944/rackspace-ubuntu-12-04-apache2-causing-out-of-memory) I still get a very suspicious activity of `sendmail`.

Any recommendations on how to tackle this issue? I think that must be some malware, but I no experience on resolving this kind of attacks.

#### htop

```
  1  [|||||||||||||||||||||||||                                                          27.0%]     Tasks: 101, 50 thr; 1 running
  2  [|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                                          45.7%]     Load average: 12.96 12.55 11.95 
  Mem[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||1183/1995MB]     Uptime: 09:53:28
  Swp[||||                                                                           93/2047MB]

  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
19704 root       20   0  120M 25328  2896 S  2.0  1.2  0:46.16 sendmail: MTA: ./s6HH4rLv009027 gmail.co.: user open
 3298 root       20   0   99M  5612  1684 S  2.0  0.3  2:46.31 sendmail: MTA: s6OABpf4003298 localhost [127.0.0.1]: DATA
 3301 root       20   0   99M  5544  1684 S  2.0  0.3  2:40.89 sendmail: MTA: s6OAGAAh003301 localhost [127.0.0.1]: DATA
19510 root       20   0 26488  2568  1212 R  2.0  0.1  0:23.73 htop
  771 syslog     20   0  244M  3892   516 S  1.0  0.2  2:22.43 rsyslogd -c5
 1226 smmsp      20   0  133M 56328  1396 S  0.0  2.8  1:56.85 sendmail: MSP: ./s6K1OdvJ030780 [127.0.0.1]: client DATA status
32488 root       20   0  102M  7168  2748 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.02 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OAcr6I032488 aspmx.l.google.com.: client EHLO
31723 www-data   39  19  448M 72676 47276 S  0.0  3.6  0:01.14 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
29624 root       20   0  120M 25916  2884 S  0.0  1.3  0:29.65 sendmail: MTA: ./s6NHPdHs002287 todito.com.: user open
  898 mysql      20   0 1315M  105M  3296 S  0.0  5.3 23:25.23 /usr/sbin/mysqld
30966 root       20   0  101M  5092   460 D  0.0  0.2  0:01.52 sendmail: MTA: running queue: /var/spool/mqueue
 5013 mysql      20   0 1315M  105M  3296 S  0.0  5.3  0:25.58 /usr/sbin/mysqld
25504 root       20   0  120M 25904  2900 S  0.0  1.3  0:24.57 sendmail: MTA: ./s6JHcEdS028616 hotamil.com.: user open
 1033 root       20   0  630M  6228  2356 S  0.0  0.3  1:17.85 /usr/local/bin/driveclient --daemon
 1062 root       20   0  630M  6228  2356 S  0.0  0.3  0:12.50 /usr/local/bin/driveclient --daemon
 1082 newrelic   20   0  107M  1576  1072 S  0.0  0.1  0:46.81 /usr/sbin/nrsysmond -c /etc/newrelic/nrsysmond.cfg -p /var/run/nrsysmond.pid
 1089 newrelic   20   0  107M  1576  1072 S  0.0  0.1  0:46.80 /usr/sbin/nrsysmond -c /etc/newrelic/nrsysmond.cfg -p /var/run/nrsysmond.pid
  822 syslog     20   0  244M  3892   516 S  0.0  0.2  1:35.12 rsyslogd -c5
 1061 root       20   0  630M  6228  2356 S  0.0  0.3  0:12.80 /usr/local/bin/driveclient --daemon
 8532 root       20   0  105M  9444   460 D  0.0  0.5  0:06.40 sendmail: MTA: running queue: /var/spool/mqueue
31711 www-data   39  19  445M 75316 52764 S  0.0  3.7  0:01.50 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
27927 root       20   0  120M 25904  2900 S  0.0  1.3  0:32.35 sendmail: MTA: ./s6NKLEhE005721 yahoo.co.: user open
13821 mysql      20   0 1315M  105M  3296 S  0.0  5.3  2:25.39 /usr/sbin/mysqld
31924 mysql      20   0 1315M  105M  3296 S  0.0  5.3  0:49.12 /usr/sbin/mysqld
31713 www-data   39  19  446M 68484 45496 S  0.0  3.4  0:00.79 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 4195 mysql      20   0 1315M  105M  3296 S  0.0  5.3  0:29.08 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 9799 mysql      20   0 1315M  105M  3296 S  0.0  5.3  2:29.95 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 2664 smmsp      20   0  133M 56424  1476 D  0.0  2.8  1:52.68 sendmail: MSP: ./s6K3MC7s027126 [127.0.0.1]: client DATA status
  853 syslog     20   0  244M  3892   516 S  0.0  0.2  0:47.23 rsyslogd -c5
31714 www-data   39  19  446M 68404 45420 S  0.0  3.3  0:00.73 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
31903 mysql      20   0 1315M  105M  3296 S  0.0  5.3  0:47.96 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 1063 root       20   0  630M  6228  2356 S  0.0  0.3  0:12.40 /usr/local/bin/driveclient --daemon
31600 www-data   39  19  448M 71340 46228 S  0.0  3.5  0:00.92 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 4308 mysql      20   0 1315M  105M  3296 S  0.0  5.3  0:28.28 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 1064 root       20   0  630M  6228  2356 S  0.0  0.3  0:12.41 /usr/local/bin/driveclient --daemon
31727 www-data   39  19  447M 70324 45756 S  0.0  3.4  0:00.84 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
31725 www-data   39  19  447M 70340 45756 S  0.0  3.4  0:00.86 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
31724 www-data   39  19  447M 70548 45932 S  0.0  3.5  0:00.84 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1715 mysql      20   0 1315M  105M  3296 S  0.0  5.3  3:05.00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
23774 root       39  19  425M  6636  4676 S  0.0  0.3  0:06.00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1065 root       20   0  630M  6228  2356 S  0.0  0.3  0:12.35 /usr/local/bin/driveclient --daemon
 1060 root       20   0  630M  6228  2356 S  0.0  0.3  0:12.43 /usr/local/bin/driveclient --daemon
F1Help  F2Setup F3SearchF4FilterF5Tre
```

#### huge /var/mail

```
root@web:/var/mail# ls -alh
total 1.2G
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     mail 4.0K Jul 24 10:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root 4.0K Jul 24 00:45 ..
-rw-rw----  1 munin    mail  83K Jul 19 18:48 munin
-rw-------  1 root     mail 1.1G Jul 24 10:51 root
-rw-rw----  1 www-data mail  98M Jul 23 22:34 www-data
```

My root mail account is continuously sending emails

NOTE: I have replace my domain by `filtered.com`

```
Return-Path: <MAILER-DAEMON>
Received: from localhost (localhost)
    by web.filtered.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-2ubuntu2) id s6OAqpuv010033;
    Thu, 24 Jul 2014 10:52:51 GMT
Date: Thu, 24 Jul 2014 10:52:51 GMT
From: Mail Delivery Subsystem <MAILER-DAEMON>
Message-Id: <201407241052.s6OAqpuv010033@web.filtered.com>
To: <kara_velazquez@filtered.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="s6OAqpuv010033.1406199171/web.filtered.com"
Subject: Returned mail: see transcript for details
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated (failure)

--s6OAqpuw010033.1406199172/web.filtered.com--

From MAILER-DAEMON  Thu Jul 24 10:52:53 2014
Return-Path: <MAILER-DAEMON>
Received: from localhost (localhost)
    by web.filtered.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-2ubuntu2) id s6OAqq6J010047;
    Thu, 24 Jul 2014 10:52:53 GMT
Date: Thu, 24 Jul 2014 10:52:53 GMT
From: Mail Delivery Subsystem <MAILER-DAEMON>
Message-Id: <201407241052.s6OAqq6J010047@web.filtered.com>
To: postmaster
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="s6OAqq6J010047.1406199173/web.filtered.com"
Subject: Postmaster notify: see transcript for details
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated (postmaster-notification)

This is a MIME-encapsulated message

--s6OAqq6J010047.1406199173/web.filtered.com

The original message was received at Thu, 24 Jul 2014 10:52:52 GMT
from localhost
with id s6OAqq6I010047

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<audra_gray@filtered.com>
    (reason: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to aspmx.l.google.com.:
>>> RCPT To:<audra_gray@filtered.com>
<<< 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
<<< 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
<<< 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
<<< 550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 sq8si14059110obc.83 - gsmtp
550 5.1.1 <audra_gray@filtered.com>... User unknown
>>> DATA
<<< 503 5.5.1 RCPT first. sq8si14059110obc.83 - gsmtp

--s6OAqq6J010047.1406199173/web.filtered.com
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; web.filtered.com
Received-From-MTA: DNS; localhost
Arrival-Date: Thu, 24 Jul 2014 10:52:52 GMT

Final-Recipient: RFC822; audra_gray@filtered.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Remote-MTA: DNS; aspmx.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
Last-Attempt-Date: Thu, 24 Jul 2014 10:52:53 GMT

--s6OAqq6J010047.1406199173/web.filtered.com
Content-Type: text/rfc822-headers

Return-Path: <MAILER-DAEMON>
Received: from localhost (localhost)
    by web.filtered.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-2ubuntu2) id s6OAqq6I010047;
    Thu, 24 Jul 2014 10:52:52 GMT
Date: Thu, 24 Jul 2014 10:52:52 GMT
From: Mail Delivery Subsystem <MAILER-DAEMON>
Message-Id: <201407241052.s6OAqq6I010047@web.filtered.com>
To: <audra_gray@filtered.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="s6OAqq6I010047.1406199172/web.filtered.com"
Subject: Returned mail: see transcript for details
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated (failure)

--s6OAqq6J010047.1406199173/web.filtered.com--
```

#### ps -ef | grep sendmail

```
root@web:/var/mail# ps -ef | grep sendmail
smmsp     1226     1  0 00:45 ?        00:02:04 sendmail: MSP: ./s6KKDDVU014035 [127.0.0.1]: client DATA status
smmsp     2644  2641  0 01:00 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp
smmsp     2647  2644  0 01:00 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp
smmsp     2664  2647  0 01:00 ?        00:01:58 sendmail: MSP: [127.0.0.1]: idle              
root      3298     1  1 07:57 ?        00:03:16 sendmail: MTA: s6OB1dam003298 localhost [127.0.0.1]: DATA
root      3301     1  1 07:57 ?        00:03:05 sendmail: MTA: server localhost [127.0.0.1] cmd read
root     19675     1  0 11:20 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBKJuv019675 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     19689     1  0 11:20 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBKLuv019689 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     19800     1  0 11:20 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBKbuv019800 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     20178     1  0 11:21 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBLSuv020178 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     20270     1  0 11:21 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBLZuv020270 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     20537     1  0 11:21 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBM0uv020537 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     20646     1  0 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBM5uv020646 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     21006     1  0 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBMZ6I021006 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     21015     1  0 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBMZ6I021015 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     21027     1  0 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBMauv021027 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     21036     1  0 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBMb6I021036 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     21063     1  0 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBMeuv021063 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     21065     1  0 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBMg6I021065 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     21086     1  1 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBMg6I021086 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     21094     1  0 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBMg6I021094 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     21098     1  2 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBMg6I021098 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     21103     1  1 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBMg6I021103 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     21105     1  1 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBMguv021105 aspmx.l.google.com.: client DATA 354
root     21108     1  0 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OB1dag003298 mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net.: client MAIL
root     21111     1  0 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OBMg6I021111 aspmx.l.google.com.: client RCPT
root     21113     1  0 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OAsOi1003301 mx-ha03.web.de.: client greeting
root     21117     1  1 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OAsOi3003301 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.: client DATA status
root     21123     1  0 11:22 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s6OAsOi5003301 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.: client EHLO
root     21127 18604  0 11:22 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sendmail
```

#### Sendmail status

```
root@web:/var/mail# /etc/init.d/sendmail status
MSP: is run via cron (20m)
MTA: is not running
QUE: Same as MTA
```

#### /var/spool/mqueue

```
root@web:/var/spool# ls -alh
total 48M
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  root  4.0K Mar 29  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root  root  4.0K Jul 24 00:45 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  root  4.0K May  1  2012 cron
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root     7 May  1  2012 mail -> ../mail
drwxr-s---  2 smmta smmsp  14M Jul 24 11:44 mqueue
drwxrws---  2 smmsp smmsp  34M Jul 24 12:25 mqueue-client
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4.0K Apr 13  2012 plymouth
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4.0K Mar 30  2012 rsyslog


root@web:/var/spool# du -h -d 1
4.0K    ./plymouth
1.6G    ./mqueue    <=====
4.0K    ./rsyslog
```

One message from /var/spool/mqueue

```
root@web:/var/spool/mqueue# more qfs6OBTUZY003298 
V8
T1406201622
K1406201622
N1
P120781
I202/1/476577
MDeferred: 421 4.7.1 : (DYN:T1) http://postmaster.info.aol.com/errors/421dynt1.html
Fbs
$_localhost [127.0.0.1]
$rESMTP
$sweb.anybots.com
${daemon_flags}
${if_addr}127.0.0.1
S<patty_jennings@anybots.com>
MDeferred: 421 4.7.1 : (DYN:T1) http://postmaster.info.aol.com/errors/421dynt1.html
rRFC822; neve7@aim.com
RPFD:<neve7@aim.com>
H?P?Return-Path: <?g>
H??Received: from web.anybots.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by web.anybots.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-2ubuntu2) with ESMTP id s6OBTUZY003298
    for <neve7@aim.com>; Thu, 24 Jul 2014 11:33:42 GMT
H??Received: (from www-data@localhost)
    by web.anybots.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id s6JHVJId026134;
    Sat, 19 Jul 2014 17:31:19 GMT
H??Date: Sat, 19 Jul 2014 17:31:19 GMT
H??Message-Id: <201407191731.s6JHVJId026134@web.anybots.com>
H??X-Authentication-Warning: web.anybots.com: www-data set sender to patty_jennings@anybots.com using -f
H??To: neve7@aim.com
H??Subject: Fw:  Hi Generic Drugs Online Products
H??X-PHP-Originating-Script: 33:dirs.php
H??From: "Patty Jennings" <patty_jennings@anybots.com>
H??Reply-To:"Patty Jennings" <patty_jennings@anybots.com>
H??X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
H??MIME-Version: 1.0
H??Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
H??Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
.
```

Comment: What's in your mail logs?

Comment: I updated my question accordingly. Looks like my root account is continuously send emails out. I can I stop this?

Comment: Could we get the whole of one message from `root`'s mailspool, rather than bits of two?  Each new message will start with `From ` (note trailing space) on a new line.  It would also be helpful if you didn't redact your domain.

Comment: I figured that I could just enter `mail` and get a sent email, but the server is getting very slow and I am not able to start `mail`. Do you have a hack to suggest? BTW I am filtering the domain cause I do have enough trouble. Don't want to expose my domain unnecessarily. I suppose you will understand. I wouldn't mind sharing with you privately.

Comment: Stop `sendmail` so that the server isn't dying under load while you look into the problem.  I understand the desire to redact the domain, but you're having the problem already; surely anything that helps us fix it is useful.  I can point you at any number of questions on SF that were only solved because questioners didn't redact details.

Comment: Sorry MadHatter, I am a little rusty with linux `mail`, I figured `tail -f /var/mail/root` would be enough, I just can't figure out to get a full message trace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15933/discussion-between-joelmaranhao-and-madhatter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem may be caused by **HUGE** number of (spam) messages in both sendmail queues.
(see https://serverfault.com/a/490890/163277 )

Check number of message in both sendmail queues

```
sendmail -O QueueSortOrder=none -Am -bp
sendmail -O QueueSortOrder=none -Ac -bp
```

The most memory consuming sendmail process looks like MTA queue processing (-Am).  The remaning looks like transfers from MSA to MTA queue and first time delivery attempts to external servers after such transfer.

---

You may use `qtool.pl` script to move messages send by www-data (web server) to another queue/directory.  It is provided in contrib directory of sendmail.org distribution and in sendmail-base package by Debian-Linux.

Comment: Yes indeed, that looks like it. The first command you propose is spitting out hundreds of deferred emails. How do I empty these queues? and what could be causing this?

Comment: Ok I found some suggestion [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/147676/how-do-i-permanently-delete-e-mail-messages-in-the-sendmail-queue-and-keep-them) ... I will update my question accordingly. I still need to understand how this happened though. Puzzling me

Comment: The appearance of user `www-data` in the logs suggests that you may have a web form that's allowing people to send arbitrary content to arbitrary recipients.  Do the dates on these messages correlate with anything in your web logs?

Comment: @MadHatter AFAIK you need logging at web server level.  Sendmail sees only sending user (one www-data rubber bag). Wordpress seems to use PHPMailer class - the following link MAY be helpfull [Iresult of very quick search] http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-log-emails-sent-with-phps-mail-function-to-detect-form-spam

Comment: Guys, both your input and help has been huge. I wouldn't have nailed it without you. The best help in 4 years using the StackExchange. We had web forms injected into our Wordpress before, so it's a great lead. I have made an `rsync` copy of the whole folder before I started fixing up my instance. I am currently investigating the cause. I will keep you posted on my findings.

Comment: @joël any findings? I'm running into this same issue on my server. Very informative thread!